# Concurrently using std::regex, defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, regex, multithreading, c++11

> Is it possible to use a `std::regex` object in multiple threads all using `std::sregex_iterator`, `std::regex_match`, etc.?

For instance, would the following produce logical behaviour:

```
bool SomeFunc( const std::string& szString1, const std::string& szString2 ) 
{
     static const std::regex regexTest( "=== ([\\w]+) ===", std::regex_constants::optimize );

     std::future<bool> f = std::async( []( std::string szString ) {
        return std::regex_match( szString, regexTest );  
     }, szString1 );

     bool b = std::regex_match( szString2, regexTest );

     return (b && f.get());
}
```

I can't find anything which states whether using a `const std::regex` concurrently results in undefined behaviour or not. As far as I can tell, no edits are being made to the regex object so no undefined behaviour should be induced by using it concurrently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, a `const std::regex` is thread-safe. Actually any const method in the standard library is thread-safe, see:

> §17.6.5.9/3. A C++ standard library function shall not directly or
>   indirectly modify objects (1.10) accessible by threads other than the
>   current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly
>   via the function’s non-const arguments, including this.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figured; I just wanted confirmation.

Comment: @ronag Could you explain in your answer why they chose for this specification? Also how is this achieved with a class which isn't part of the C++ standard library? I hope you will find the time to answer those questions! :)

Comment: @Tim "_Also how is this achieved with a class which isn't part of the C++ standard library?_" I don't understand your question...

Comment: @curiousguy Sorry I meant something else; the statement says that a `const` instance of any class called by a function from the C++ standard library is thread-safe, right? What if I want to make my own function thread-safe?

Comment: @ronag How? Is the C++ standard library using `std::atomic` or  `std::mutex` in their functions? I just want to know how to achieve that while maintaining performance.

Comment: @Tim: The C++ standard does not specify how things should be implemented in the standard library, it's totally up to each standard library implementer. I think you are looking for another question. But yes there are several tools to achieve thread-safety, std::atomic, std::mutex, thread_local etc...

Comment: @Tim If you want to know how to write "thread safe" classes, you need to ask a proper question; it is a non trivial topic not appropriate for comments.

Comment: afaik anything const is thread safe unless it is bitfield... but im not sure... you should prob check out you dont know const and mutable talk from herb

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: There is no "unless" in the C++11 standard library, and no guarantees outside of the standard library.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Yes? That does not contradict my statement. Bitfields are not used anywhere in the C++11 standard library interface.

Comment: "afaik anything const" aka i never said std lib... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case your statement is wrong, anything const outside of the standard library has no thread-safety guarantee whatsoever from the standards point of view, not just bitfields.

Comment: @ronag watch sutters video

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: I have. He says how things *should* be or *should* mean, but there is no guarantee from the standard for the behavior outside of the standard library. You will have explicitly to point out where I am wrong, otherwise this discussion will not be meaningful.

Comment: "Starting with C++11, const on a variable that is possibly shared means “read-only or as good as read-only” for the purposes of concurrency. Concurrent const operations on the same object are required to be safe without the calling code doing external synchronization."

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Yes, that is what HERB says how YOU should be implementing const. But the STANDARD does not guarantee or require const objects to be thread-safe outside of the standard library. If I am wrong please point to the right clause in the standard library. Thus I would only assume that const methods are thread-safe if the implementer explicitly says that is the case, otherwise it is unspecified.

Comment: tbh idk how could you write a code that breaks herbs requirements and not get into UB territory since AFAIK as soon as you have data races that is UB...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Well, you can break Herbs requirements and not go into UB, as long as you are not using the object concurrently. Not saying that you should, just saying that it is possible, and the standard does not have anything explicitly against it, AFAIK. I.e. do not simply assume that something is thread-safe just because it is const, outside of the standard library, check the documentation or implementation.

Comment: but you are right, i could make my vector and mark push_back as const :)